# simple query for new learner

Tags: sql

Just need help for new sql learner.

I have two tables. PRODUCT, VENDOR. Product has Vendor_ID as an foreign key. I need to show vendor_name, vendor_phone and number of products from each vendor.
I would be greatfull if you help me with simple explanation of query.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.  You should show any attempt you have made.  Otherwise, how are you going to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `COUNT(*)` using `GROUP BY` like following.

```
SELECT V.VendorId, V.Vendor_Name AS VendorName, V.Vendor_Phone, Count(*) [Count]
FROM Vendor V INNER JOIN Product P ON P.Vendor_ID = V.Vendor_ID 
GROUP BY  V.VendorId, V.Vendor_Name,V.Vendor_Phone
```

Or using sub query like following.

```
SELECT V.Vendor_Name AS VendorName, V.Vendor_Phone,
  (
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product P WHERE P.Vendor_ID = V.Vendor_ID 
  ) AS [Count]
FROM Vendor V
```

You can also do it using `ROW_NUMBER()`, like following.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT V.VendorId, V.Vendor_Name AS VendorName, V.Vendor_Phone, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY V.Vendor_ID  ORDER BY V.Vendor_ID) RN
            Count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY V.Vendor_ID  ORDER BY V.Vendor_ID) [Count]
    FROM Vendor V INNER JOIN Product P ON P.Vendor_ID = V.Vendor_ID 
) T
WHERE T.RN=1
```